# Usar nombres de campos en una consulta preparada con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

La conexión la hago con este php:

```
class Conexion extends PDO { 
    private $tipo_de_base = 'mysql';
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $nombre_de_base = 'basededatos';
    private $usuario = 'user';
    private $contrasena = 'user'; 

    public function __construct() {
        //Sobreescribo el método constructor de la clase PDO
        try{

            parent::__construct($this->tipo_de_base.':host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->nombre_de_base, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena);

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            echo 'Ha surgido un error y no se puede conectar a la base de datos. Detalle: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;

        }
     } 
   }
```

Mi index es mas o menos asi:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
require 'funcs_pdo.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <br>
   <?php echo getValor('usuario', 'id', '10'); ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

fucs_pdo es un archivo php donde pienso alojar funciones varias... ahora bien esa funcion getValor tiene esto:

```
    function getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor) {
    echo $campo . '<br>'; 
    echo $campoWhere . '<br>'; 
    echo $valor . '<br>'; 

    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT :campo FROM usuarios WHERE :campoWhere = :valor LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':campo', $campo); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':campoWhere', $campoWhere); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $valor); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $registro = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $num;

    if ($num > 0) {
        echo $registro;
        return $registro['nombre'];
    } else {
        echo 'NO FUNCIONA';
        return null;
    }
   }
```

El tema de la conexión no es el problema. El problema está en la función porque me devuelve nada y el registro existe.
Lo que note es que, pasando solamente el valor `WHERE` funciona, es decir, hay algo en el `SELECT` que no funciona., no sé si `:campo` y el `:campoWhere` los toma como los estoy definiendo. 
¿Alguna sugerencia ?

---

SOLUCION PROPUESTA:

```
function getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor) {
    $campoOrig = $campo;
    $campoWhereOrig = $campoWhere;
    $campo = "`".str_replace("`","``",$campo)."`";
    $campoWhere = "`".str_replace("`","``",$campoWhere)."`";

    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT $campo FROM usuarios WHERE $campoWhere = :valor LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':valor', $valor); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $registro = $stmt->fetch();

    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $num;

    if ($num > 0) {
        return $registro[$campoOrig];
    } else {
        echo 'NO FUNCIONA';
        return null;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Por favor enséña el código que tienes dentro de **conexión.php**, aunque sepas que el problema no está ahí debes compartir ese contenido.

Comment: También te recomiendo que mires el archivo error.log que genera Apache y donde puedes ver todos los errores, te será de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la clase `PDO` no acepta marcadores de posición (placeholders, o las famosas "?" o ":variable") para los identificadores (nombres de campos o tablas) y hay que hacerlo manualmente.

Para darle formato a un identificador y que pueda ser incluido en la consulta, hay dos consejos a seguir

1. Incluir el identificador en comillas invertidas
2. Duplicar las comillas invertidas para escaparlas

Un ejemplo, aplicado a tu problema podria ser el siguiente:

```
$campoWhere = "`".str_replace("`","``",$campoWhere)."`";
```

Como ves incluimos las comillas invertidas y las duplicamos. De esta manera podemos incluir directamente la variable `$campoWhere` en la consulta, algo asi:

```
"SELECT :campo FROM usuarios WHERE $campoWhere = :valor LIMIT 1;"
```

Para mas información de porque la clase PDO no tiene placeholders para identificadores puedes ver [este enlace](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like) o la [documentación oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Uh !!! que pena !!! yo tenía una función en MSQLi que recuperaba cualquier valor de cualquier campo con algo bastante parecido... quiere decir que me conviene hacer una funcion por cada tipo de consulta que necesito... porque esa solución que me propusiste, si bien veo en la documentación que está asi, no funciona. Me sale un error que dice Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Si decides hacerlo asi, recuerda que tendrias que eliminar esta linea `$stmt->bindParam(':campoWhere', $campoWhere);`  ya que no necesitas mas ese parametro.

Comment: si si... ahi me di cuenta y el error es otro... Undefined index: `usuario` y puse return $registro[$campo];

Comment: Si no estoy mal, me parece que es el mismo problema. `usuario` es un campo de tu tabla y para nombres de campos o nombres de tablas, PDO no tiene placeholders. Creo que tendras que hacer lo mismo con tu variable `$campo`

Comment: si elimine campo y campoWhere... ahora edito el post y agrego como me quedo pero sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Y cual es el error que obtienes?

Comment: Undefined index: `usuario` in C:\wamp\www\pdo\funcs_pdo.php on line 18 LA LINEA 18 ES DONDE ESTA: echo $registro[$campo]; y mismo error en la linea 19 donde esta: return $registro[$campo];

Comment: $num = $stmt->rowCount(); me esta devolviendo un numero 1 es decir que hay algo...

Comment: A bueno, gracias por mostrarme el error. Eso es porque modificaste la variable $campo, recuerdas? Ahora lo que esta en campo tiene comillas dobles invertidas y por eso en tu tabla no hay ningun campo como ese. Lo mejor entonces seria guardar el campo que insertaras en la consulta en una variable adicional para que no te modifique la original. En vez de `$campo = "`".str_replace("`","``",$campo)."`";` mejor considera otra variable como `$campo1 = "`".str_replace("`","``",$campo)."`";` y por supuesto en tu consulta poner `SELECT $campo1....`

Comment: excelente !!!... medio rebuscado el PDO no ?... pero si hay que hacerlo por seguridad en la aplicación, no queda otra... voy a seguir consultando cosas como estas ya que tengo que redefinir toda mi aplicación que estaba en msqli a pdo

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Esto **es una restricción del SGBD no de PDO**. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html @Kenny