# Error al realizar consulta con PDO

Tags: php, pdo

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''inventory' WHERE 'Inv_User' = 'gmarsi'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\qbc_web\funciones\funciones_contador.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\qbc_web\funciones\funciones_contador.php(14): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\qbc_web\login\profile.php(75): contarElementos('Inv_User', 'inventory', 'Inv_User', 'gmarsi') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qbc_web\funciones\funciones_contador.php on line 14

Me da este error al generar la consulta, el código es este:

```
function contarElementos($element, $table, $condition, $purchased){    
        require(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'/qbc_web/datos_conexion.php');         

    $consulta = "SELECT COUNT(:element) AS Contador FROM :table WHERE :condition = :purchased";

    $result = $base -> prepare($consulta);

    $result -> bindValue(':element', $element);
    $result -> bindValue(':table', $table);
    $result -> bindValue(':condition', $condition);
    $result -> bindValue(':purchased', $purchased);
    $result -> execute();
    $sql_contador = $result->rowCount();


    if($sql_contador < 1){
            return 0;
    }else{
       while($fila = $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
            return $fila['Contador'];
        }
    }    
    // echo $consulta;
}
```

La función básicamente lo que hace es contar los elementos de X tabla teniendo en cuenta los parámetros que se le introducen. Como se puede ver en el error aparece `contarElementos('Inv_User', 'inventory', 'Inv_User', 'gmarsi')` que son los parámetros que quiero que use la función para hacer la consulta a la base de datos. A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Los nombres de tabla y los nombres de columna no se pueden pasar en parámetro en PDO. Esto es erróneo: `SELECT COUNT(:element) AS Contador FROM :table WHERE :condition` a lo sumo debería ser algo como: `SELECT COUNT($element) AS Contador FROM $table WHERE $condition ...` guardado de pasar los valores en parámetros, eso es lo más importante de cara a la Inyeccion SQL.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Usar nombres de campos en una consulta preparada con PDO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88379/usar-nombres-de-campos-en-una-consulta-preparada-con-pdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los nombres de tabla y los nombres de columna no se pueden pasar en parámetro cuando usamos consultas preparadas, como ocurre en este caso usando PDO.

Se puede ver en la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html):

> ... Dentro de la declaración, los caracteres `?` se pueden utilizar
>   como marcadores de parámetros para indicar dónde se van a vincular los
>   valores de datos a la consulta más adelante cuando se ejecute. Los
>   caracteres `?`  no se deben encerrar entre comillas, incluso si tiene
>   la intención de vincularlos a valores de cadena. **Los marcadores de
>   parámetros sólo se pueden utilizar en los valores de datos que deben
>   aparecer, no para palabras clave SQL, identificadores (nombres de
>   tablas, de columnas...), etc**.

Lo dicho más arriba aplica tambien para los marcadores de `:nombre`.

Por tanto, esto es erróneo:

<s>SELECT COUNT(:element) AS Contador FROM :table WHERE :condition...</s>

a lo sumo debería ser algo como:

```
"SELECT COUNT($element) AS Contador FROM $table WHERE $condition ..."
```

guardado de pasar los valores en parámetros, eso es lo más importante de cara a la Inyeccion SQL:

<s>$result -> bindValue(':element', $element);</s>

<s>$result -> bindValue(':table', $table);</s>

<s>$result -> bindValue(':condition', $condition);</s>

```
//Este es el valor importante para pasar en parámetro
$result -> bindValue(':purchased', $purchased);
```

---

Por otra parte, el uso de `rowCount` para saber si hay datos es un *mito* muy difundido en PDO.

Si quieres saber si hay datos, actúa sobre los mismos datos, así te evitas el `rowCount` suplementario, optimizando el codigo. Por ejemplo:

<s>$sql_contador = $result->rowCount();</s>

```
$fila=$result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Si no hay datos $fila será `false` 
if(! $fila){
        return 0;
}else{
   while($fila){ 
        return $fila['Contador'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Solo como añadido la fuente donde se puede encontrar esta restricción es aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html

Comment: Muchas gracias @Xerif he añadido la nota traducida, actualizando la URL a la versión 8 de la documentación, pues ya no estamos en la versión 5. :) Saludos.

Comment: Ok @A. Cedano . Mucha gente piensa que esto es una restricción de PDO cuando en realidad es del SGBD. Un saludo.